# How to add a field to TFS workitem

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild

I'm a new user to TFS

I would like to add a custom field to a work item in a project in my project collection.

**My expectation is to add a custom field("BizID") to a work item "task" from **c# code** behind.**

I would like to know what all are possible ways to add a custom field to a work item?

P.S: I dont need a Process Template interruption to do this and Also not using WIT.

Some references will help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

At present time, in order to add a field to a process template in on-premise TFS, you need to modify the process template XML. There's no way around it.

You may be able to avoid using a process template customization by using some combination of custom backlog columns and tags, however. It depends on the data you want to capture.

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel mentioned, modify the process template is the only way to modify a work item type.

Besides [modifying work item type definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh409273(v=vs.110).aspx), you can also download and install [TFS Power Tool](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f), which will simplify the process of add a field. TFS Power Tool provides a UI to add fields. You can check this tool and follow this blog:

http://blog.infostructure.co.nz/2013/05/how-to-addedit-field-in-team-foundation.html